# Should I use "dancing car" or "dancer car" ?

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives, participles, idiomatic-language

> "It is a dancing car."

or

> "It is a dancer car"

Which one is idiomatic and appropriate ?

Answer (score 1):

"It is a dancing car" would be correct. Only it is not a gerund here. It is Participle I, or Present Participle. It refers to a noun, which in our case is "car", and acts like an adjective. It means the car is dancing.

Comment: And what if we talk about a guy..  A dancing boy or a dancer boy?

Comment: Dancing boy would be nice. I didn't hear the expression "dancer boy". I think you may say simply "dancer".

Comment: Whatever a dance/ing car is, I "think dance" shoes are perfectly idiomatic because English is analytic language.